# PDFJS.getDocument not working and not throwing an error

Tags: pdf.js

It's not going into the `.then` afterwards, and it's not throwing any error.

Here's my calling code:

```
function loadPage(base64Data, pageIndex) {
  var pdfData = base64ToUint8Array(base64Data); 
  // this gets hit
  PDFJS.getDocument(pdfData).then(function (pdf) { 
    // never gets here
    pdf.getPage(pageIndex).then(function (page) {
      var scale = 1;
      var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
      var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfPage');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport });
    });
  });
}

function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
  var raw = atob(base64); // convert base 64 string to raw string
  var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(raw.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
    uint8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return uint8Array;
}
```

At one point it worked. When I step through it in the debugger, I can step into `PDFJS.getDocument` but that's way over my head.

My base64Data looks like `JVBERi0x...g==`. It's a base64 encoded pdf document.

Comment: then() has second argument for failures, see PDF.js uses Promise API

Comment: @async5, I fixed it. See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to add

```
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```

to the beginning of my `loadPage` function.

From [View PDF files directly within browser using PDF.js](http://codingcrazy87.blogspot.com/2014/05/view-pdf-files-directly-within-browser.html),

> PDF.js uses Web Workers concept of HTML5 internally to process the
>   request. If this statement is set to false, it creates an instance of
>   Web workers. Web Workers run in an isolated thread. For more
>   information on web workers; please refer
>   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Promise is missing in your code. Here how i fixed this probelm:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(pdfData).promise.then(function (pdf) { 
   // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: You got downvoted, but coming here from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58728851/4267429 ,where they suggest same thing as you do. I don't understand this place sometimes...