# How to import PDFjs-dist in angular project in order to know to view-port of the pdf file

Tags: angular, pdf.js

I would like to use pdfjs-dist package in angular project. How to import it angular project

I installed it using

`npm install --save pdfjs-dist`

But don't know how to import into a particular component and work with it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After installing it, in `package.json` something look like this

```typescript
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.2.228",
    ...
    }
```

1) Now in component you could be able to import it like

```typescript
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

2) Now you could use it like bellow example

```typescript
yourMethodName() {
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf');
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    console.log(pdf);
    });
}
```

Comment: The above example also working with vuejs, @coder Can you please share the reference link where to get the other implementation with pdfjs?

Comment: you will be able to refer this [link](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/). This is part of their [DOC](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). so hope this will help you :)

Comment: This should be in the readme of the pdfjs-dist as a "Getting Started"

Comment: I have this error: Error: node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts:1466:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGGraphics'.

1466 export { SVGGraphics };